# newbie - NSHomeDirectory() returned a strange path

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS, NSHomeDirectory() returned a strange path which I dont understand:

```
NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
```

output: 
homeDir NSPathStore2 *  @"/Users/fredjones/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0BDB928B-3ED1-4C13-B1C7-39F76F46EC7C/data/Containers/Data/Application/129FA08D-873E-40DC-9316-05D2AAE9CEA7"  0x00007fde99d232f0

why is it that i can not find these folders on my mac?
what are these numbers such as "0BDB928B-3ED1-4C13-B1C7-39F76F46EC7C" ?

Comment: In Terminal `ls -la /Users/fredjones/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`, you should see it. Don't take in account this, it's just XCode's part.

Comment: but what are these folders: 0BDB928B-3ED1-4C13-B1C7-39F76F46EC7C..  for example, in windows we have system folders, is that what this is  ?

Comment: Pure speculation on my part, but since it comes under the "Devices" folder within simulator, the hex number might correspond to a virtual device identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have Library folder hidden and you can't see it in Finder. It surely exists in your filesystem.

These numbers are unique identifier of simulator.

Comment: the number is an unique identifier for the app, not for the simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can go to these folders easy with terminal:

```
cd /Users/fredjones/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0BDB928B-3ED1-4C13-B1C7-39F76F46EC7C/data/Containers/Data/Application/129FA08D-873E-40DC-9316-05D2AAE9CEA7
open .
```

And it will open the folder with your finder.

Answer (score 0):

The path exists in all systems. If you don't see the path, do one of the following:

1. Go to Finder -> Go menu -> Go to Folder... and type the path in the  box which appears in a new window. This will open the path in a finder window, even hidden.
2. Run the following code in Terminal:

   cd [PATH]

Replace [PATH] with the path you saw.

NOTE: This opens the path in Terminal. To see contents of the file, run the command:

```
ls
```

NOTE: You must insert lower and upper cases correctly in UNIX-based terminals unlike DOS-based command prompts.